# Show that every open subset of a surface is a Surface.

Tags: geometry, analysis, algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry

Show that every open subset of a surface is a Surface.

I think, first of all, i need to define an atlas $\{\sigma_{\alpha}: U_{\alpha}\to \Bbb R^3\}$ for surface S, Where $U$ is an open set.

After there, how to continue the proof? 
Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: what is the definition of surface do you use algebraic ...!? what do you mean by surface ?

Comment: In order for S to be a surface, i write a homemorphism $\sigma : U\to S\cap W$ Where U is open subset in $\Bbb R^2$ for open set $W\in \Bbb R^3$ @AbdelmajidKhadari

Comment: I saw the question while studying differential geometry. Can you help me? @AbdelmajidKhadari

Comment: if $S^{'}$ open subset of $S$ then $\sigma^{-1}(S^{'}) =U^{'}$ is open you can take the restriction $\sigma^{'}$ of $\sigma$ on $U^{'}$ and you have the homomorphisme $\sigma^{'} : U^{'}\to S^{'}\cap W$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if $S^{'}$ open subset of $S$ then $\sigma^{-1}(S^{'}) =U^{'}$ is open you can take the restriction $\sigma^{'}$ of $\sigma$ on $U^{'}$ and you have the homomorphisme $\sigma^{'} : U^{'}\to S^{'}\cap W$