# Why is the image of a proper patch an open set?

Tags: differential-geometry

O'Neill's Elementary DIfferential Geometry mentions that the image of a proper patch is always a surface. This seems to be based on the proposition that the image of a proper patch is an open set. Why is this true? I see that the domain of a patch is an open set, and the mapping is continuous. Would it be true to say that the image, under a continuous mapping, of an open set is always open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> O'Neill's Elementary DIfferential Geometry mentions that the image of a proper patch is always a surface. This seems to be based on the proposition that the image of a proper patch is an open set. Why is this true?

This is true, because every open subset of surface is surface aswell.
See [every open subset of a surface is a surface](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/578288/show-that-every-open-subset-of-a-surface-is-a-surface).

> Would it be true to say that the image, under a continuous mapping, of an open set is always open?

Well no. Consider constant function $\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ with standard metric. Image is a single point which is closed.

The keyword is here *proper*. A proper function takes open sets and maps them to open sets.

Comment: OK, every open subset of a surface is a surface. How does that apply to the case where we have a proper patch? What is the "open subset of the surface" in this case? We don't know that the image of the proper patch is an open set since that is what we are trying to prove.

Comment: @GeneNaden Let $U\subseteq \mathbb R^2$ be an open set in a domain of a  proper surface patch $\phi$. Since $\phi$ proper and $U$ open $\phi(U)$ is open set in surface (in the sense of subspace topology). Now apply " open subset of the surface is surface " on $\phi(U)$.

Comment: So $\phi(U)$ is a surface. How does that tell me that the image of $\phi$ is open?

Comment: @GeneNaden Sorry, I seem to be miserable at understanding your confusion. Image of $\phi$ is $\phi(\text{domain})$, right? Since $\phi$ is proper and domain open $\phi(\text{domain})$ is open. Furthermore $\phi(\text{domain})$ is surface (see my comment above).